# Unattended Server-Automated Access to Android Management API

Tags: android-management-api

To the best of my knowledge (and experience), `OAuth 2.0` authentication procedure displays a consent-page to the user, requiring them to manually approve app-access to the **Android Management API** ('Choose an Account', 'Allow' app-required permissions, reading a risk-note and giving a final confirmation).

Is there a way for my (PHP) server to auto-authenticate itself, as it needs to perform API operations upon
external events (e.g. data sent it from a 3rd party, requiring it to modify a policy)?

In other words, is there a way to perform an unattended authentication (not necessarily using `OAuth`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use service accounts to automatically authenticate your API calls. You can read more about them [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).